# How to find duplicate values in a column and copy paste the rows found duplicated?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, copy, copy-paste

There are **duplicated values in the first column** (ISIN numbers of financial products), **but different characteristics in the other columns** (product name, modified duration, etc.) **where should be the same characteristics**.

I want to find ISIN numbers that already exist in my first column (at least two times), then take specific elements from the other columns (of the same row that was found the duplicated value) such as issuer name, modified duration etc. and paste them to the other's ISIN elements to report the same elements (data in other columns) in case where ISIN numbers are the same.

I also want to compare the modified duration of these duplicated products and take the bigger one (for conservative reasons, because these data are used in further calculations).

```vb
Sub dup_cp()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Sheets("Investment Assets").Activate
j = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) 
'counts the number of filled in rows

For i = 5 To j
'it starts from line 5 on purpose, the ISIN numbers start from that line
    For k = i + 1 To j
        If Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 55), Cells(k, 55)).Value = "Duplicate Value" Then GoTo skip_dup 
        'it skips the line that has already been detected as duplicated
           
        If Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k, 1)).Value = Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Value Then 
        'it finds the duplicate value (ISIN number) in the first column
            If Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 29), Cells(k, 29)).Value >= Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(i, 29), Cells(i, 29)).Value Then 
            'it compares the 29th column values (the modified duration of the components) and keeps the bigger value for prudency reasons
                Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 15), Cells(k, 32)).Copy
                Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 32)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Else
                Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(i, 15), Cells(i, 32)).Copy
                Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 15), Cells(k, 32)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
            Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 55), Cells(k, 55)).Value = "Duplicate Value"
            'it shows in the 55th column if the ISIN number is duplicated or not
            Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(i, 55), Cells(i, 55)).Value = "Duplicate Value"
        Else
            Sheets("Investment Assets").Range(Cells(k, 55), Cells(k, 55)).Value = "-"
        End If
skip_dup:
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

This code works, but is messy. Can it be made simpler and faster?

Comment: `Copy` is the problem. It is slow. Also, `Activate` should be avoided, but the you would need to always tell VBA which sheet you refer to.

Comment: Agree for both. I could use instead of copy just equalities. I used activate, because there is other code before which runs using other worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed a few things. As said before, `Copy` and `Activate` are the biggest drags on performance. I have introduced a `With` statement instead of `Activate` and have changed `Copy`, `Paste` to a faster `....Value = ....Value`

```
Sub dup_cp()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

With Sheets("Investment Assets")
    j = Application.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
    'counts the number of filled in rows

    For i = 5 To j
    'it starts from line 5 on purpose, the ISIN numbers start from that line
        For k = i + 1 To j
            If .Cells(k, 55).Value = "Duplicate Value" Then GoTo skip_dup
            'it skips the line that has already been detected as duplicated

            If .Cells(k, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            'it finds the duplicate value (ISIN number) in the first column
                If .Cells(k, 29).Value >= .Cells(i, 29).Value Then
                'it compares the 29th column values (the modified duration of the components) and keeps the bigger value for prudency reasons
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 15), .Cells(i, 32)).Value = .Range(.Cells(k, 15), .Cells(k, 32)).Value
                Else
                    .Range(.Cells(k, 15), .Cells(k, 32)).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, 15), .Cells(i, 32)).Value
                End If
                .Cells(k, 55).Value = "Duplicate Value"
                'it shows in the 55th column if the ISIN number is duplicated or not
                .Cells(i, 55).Value = "Duplicate Value"
            Else
                .Cells(k, 55).Value = "-"
            End If
skip_dup:
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Old Nick's proposal is also very great for performance, but I would implement it with care, something like this:

```
Sub xxx

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Your code

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Because if you disable those things at the beginning, and then suddenly something goes wrong in the code, you might not get those things re-enabled.

Comment: I see, i wiil incorporate these changes to see the difference.
Now the code runs in 8 minutes.
Thank you.

Comment: WIth Nick's and your changes we manage to run the code in 1 minute and 16 seconds! Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything you've done (as after all you say it works), you could try disabling some of the automatic features of Excel before you call your sub:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And then re-enabling them when you return from your sub:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Hopefully you should see an improvement in execution speed by doing this